# яндекс.карты в приложение (MapKit)

Tags: yandexmapkit, mapkit

мы интегрировали яндекс.карты в приложение (MapKit), нам нужно отслеживать фактический маршрут пользователя, возможно ли такое? Если да, то скажите как или подскажите где в документации это искать.
Мы знаем, что есть функционал построения маршрутов, но для маршрута нужна начальная и конечная точка, а нам нужно отслеживать фактически преодоленное расстояние в реальном времени. Хотим што бы наш шагомер мерил пройденное расстояние на велосипеде.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблема: надо что бы пользователь открыв карту получил точку где он начал движение и и какое расстояние проехал на велосипеде, когда он закончит велопрогулку. На Гугл картах такое есть и в каждом шагомере это отражается, на Яндекс не понятно как это сделать. Мы делаем свой шагомер, но на яндекс картах

Comment: Вопрос без конкретики приводит к таким же ответам и занижению репутации.. для определения местоположения getUserLocation, для отслеживания движения watchPosition. Дальше дело техники, подробнее тут https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/quick-start/index.html. Научиться искать информацию в документации/гугле лучше самим, так быстрее, чем задавать вопросы тут и профит не заставит себя ждать :)

Comment: getUserLocation мы и используем, а watchPosition есть в geolocation api , но в mapkit android найти не удается

Answer (score 0):

В MapKit в настоящее время нет режима навигации